# wordpress creating a full-width dashboard widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, dashboard

How can I create a full-width dashboard widget in WordPress?

I want to create a widget like the new one "welcome" in WordPress 3.3.

That plugin is in `dashboard.php` in `wp_welcome_panel()` but I don't know how they show it full-width.

They create a div "welcome-panel" outside the main div where all the widgets go, "dashboard-widgets-wrap":

```
<div id="welcome-panel" class="welcome-panel"></div>
<div id="dashboard-widgets-wrap">
   <div id="dashboard-widgets" class="metabox-holder">
      <div id="postbox-container-1" class="postbox-container" style="width:50%;">
      <div id="postbox-container-2" class="postbox-container" style="width:50%;">
      <div id="postbox-container-3" class="postbox-container" style="display:none;width:50%;">
      <div id="postbox-container-4" class="postbox-container" style="display:none;width:50%;">
   </div>
```

How can I achieve that?

**Edit**

I've found in `wp-admin/index.php` in line 90 this:

```
<div class="wrap">
<?php screen_icon(); ?>
<h2><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h2>

<?php wp_welcome_panel(); ?>

<div id="dashboard-widgets-wrap">

<?php wp_dashboard(); ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- dashboard-widgets-wrap -->

</div><!-- wrap -->
```

So they do it inserting directly the code.

The only solution I see is maybe using jQuery?

Any other option?

A full-width widget can be very useful for adding content at the top of your own themes with updates or corroborative info or anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to hook into that Welcome panel.

I've got two solutions for this.

### [Manipulating the `div` with CSS and jQuery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57414/12615)

[image: modified welcome screen]

**or**

### [Injecting an iframe](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73561/12615)

In this case, I'm cleaning all the dashboard widgets, tabs, welcome panel. Forcing a one-column layout. And finally filling the void with the iframe.

But this can be easily adapted to suit your taste.

Comment: In modern versions on WordPress you can hook into the welcome panel.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with WordPress 3.5.0, you can directly modify the welcome panel:

First remove the existing content, then add your own function to render the content:

```
remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );
add_action( 'welcome_panel', 'my_custom_content' );

function my_custom_content()
{
    ?>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this goal by modifying the admin css as below:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'panfor_admin_custom_styles');
function panfor_admin_custom_styles() {
    $output_css = '<style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1499px) {
        #dashboard-widgets #postbox-container-1 { width: 100% !important; }
        #dashboard-widgets #postbox-container-2 { width: 50% !important; }
        #dashboard-widgets #postbox-container-3 { width: 50% !important; }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width: 1800px) {
        #dashboard-widgets #postbox-container-1 { width: 100% !important; }
        #dashboard-widgets #postbox-container-2 { width: 50% !important; }
        #dashboard-widgets #postbox-container-3 { width: 50% !important; }
    }
    </style>';
    echo $output_css;
}
```

The above code enforces full width for all widgets in the first column of Dashboard for certain screen widths. The second and third columns are displayed below first colum.

[This is what it looks like in my Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fMJT.png)

So it is not the widget as such that determines its width, but the css styles.

There is still a small problem in my CSS that I cannot solve. Namely, the second and third columns switch places, depending on the width of the window.